# How to remove an entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity

This is my first time using symfony framework. I am trying to learn Doctrine. I have created and entity class. I have created an entity called Product. But since there was something wrong I deleted the Entity folder and now I am trying to create one again. But the framework is not allowing me to do so. It saying that an entity class already exists. How do I remove my previous entity class?

Comment: what do you mean? if you're deleting the class file only, that doesn't mean that you have deleted db table also.

Comment: there is no table in the database

Comment: I have deleted the entity folder in my bundle

Comment: Could you paste the error log?

Comment: Empty out your cache folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to clear doctrine cache:

```
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

Answer (score 0):

Chen creating your Product entity, what type of mapping do you pick ? XML, YAML, Annotation ?

If you pick XML or YAML, then you got an external file that define your mapping, maybe it's this file that is blocking you.
Take a look to `src/Path/To/Your/Bundle/Resources/config/doctrine`.